# $m$-fold character product

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory

Here is an interesting and long exercise from the book "Character Theory of finite groups : I.M. Isaacs" (usually handled by wedge products)

Let $V$ be a ${\mathbb{C}}[G]$-module with basis $\{ v_1, \dotsc, v_n \}$ and let $p$ be a prime. Let $W = \underbrace{V \otimes \dotsc \otimes V}_p$ and define $\alpha$ on $W$ so that $\left( x_1 \otimes \dotsc \otimes x_p \right)^{\alpha} = x_2 \otimes \dotsc \otimes x_p \otimes x_1 ~~ (x_1, \dotsc, x_p \in V)$.

Let $\epsilon$ be a primitive $p$-th root of unity in ${\mathbb{C}}$. Let 
$W_1 = \{ w \in W ~:~ w^{\alpha} = \epsilon w \}$. 
Show that $W_1$ is a ${\mathbb{C}}[G]$-submodule of $W$ which affords the character $\chi_1 = (\chi^p - \chi^{(p)})/p$, where $\chi$ is the character afforded by $V$. Conclude that $\chi^{(m)}$ is a difference of characters for all $m \geq 1$.

[Here $\chi^p(g) = \chi(g)^p$ and $\chi^{(p)}(g) = \chi(g^p)$.]

I followed the interesting hint to construct the invariant subspace to construct the character $\chi_1$ :

Let ${\mathscr{W}} = \left\{ v_{i_1} \otimes \dotsc \otimes v_{i_p} ~:~ i_{j_1} \neq i_{j_2} ~~ {\mathrm{for~some}} ~~ i_{j_1}, i_{j_2} \right\}$. For $w \in {\mathscr{W}}$, let ${\overline{w}} = w + \epsilon^{-1} w^{\alpha} + \epsilon^{-2} w^{\alpha^2} + \dotsc + \epsilon^{-(p-1)} w^{\alpha^{p-1}}$. Now $\langle \alpha \rangle$ permutes ${\mathscr{W}}$ into orbits of size $p$. Let ${\mathscr{W}}_0$ denote a set of representatives of these orbits. Then $\{ {\overline{w}} ~:~ w \in {\mathscr{W}}_0 \}$ is a basis of $W_1$.

Until this point it went smooth. Now it's turn to verify $p \chi_1(g) = \chi^p(g) - \chi^{(p)}(g)$. Here I got the following sums which I am unable to equate as it require to make the powers of $\epsilon$ in $p \chi_1(g)$ to disappear somehow :

$$\chi_1(g) = \sum_{ v_{i_1} \otimes \dotsc v_{i_p} \in {\mathscr{W}}_0} \sum_{k=0}^{p-1} \epsilon^k \alpha_{i_1 i_{\sigma^{k}(1)}} \alpha_{i_2 i_{\sigma^{k}(2)}} \dotsc \alpha_{i_p i_{\sigma^{k}(p)}}$$

where $\sigma = (1, 2, \dotsc, p) \in S_p$ is the cyclic permutations. Obviously $\chi^p(g) = \left( \sum_{i=1}^{n} \alpha_{ii} \right)^p$ and

$$\chi^{(p)}(g) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j_1 = 1}^{n} \dotsc \sum_{j_{p-1} = 1}^{n} \alpha_{i j_1} \alpha_{j_1 j_2} \dotsc \alpha_{j_{p-1} i}.$$

Finally how come $\chi^{(m)}$ for an arbitrary $m \geq 1$ is connected to this?

Comment: I'm not sure this is of the right level for MathOverflow. For the first part, you can simplify notation by taking a basis of $V$ of eigenvectors for $g$. The case $p=2$ (where the cyclic symmetry gives the symmetric square so the formula is well known) shows most of the general argument. To reduce to the prime case: we have $\chi^{(pc)} = (\chi^{(p)})^{(c)}$. By the prime case $\chi^{(p)}$ is a difference of two characters, say $\theta- \phi$. So $\chi^{(pc)} = \theta^{(c)} - \phi^{(c)}$ and by induction, each of $\theta^{(c)}$ and $\phi^{(c)}$ is a difference of two characters.

Comment: Thanks. The second part is clear. For the first part the formula for $p=2$ is very simple (Thm4.5, same reference) and as far as I see there is no requirement of involving sign (in this case $\epsilon = -1$). While we add up terms of $p \chi_1(g)$ for $p$ odd, certain rearrangement must cause vanishing of several terms using the sum formula which I don't notice.

Comment: Sorry, I should have written 'antisymmetric' above, so there is a sign of $-1$. I just checked the case $p=3$ and it worked as I expected. I think your error is in the formula for $\chi_1(g)$: there should not be any powers of $\epsilon$. E.g. for the case $p=2$, the basis vectors are (using eigenvectors $v_1,\ldots, v_d$ with eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_d$) all $v_i \otimes v_j - v_j \otimes v_i$ for $i < j$, with eigenvalue $\lambda_i \lambda_j$. So $\chi_1(g) = \sum_{i < j} \lambda_i\lambda_j$, with no signs.